# Does $2^c=2^d \implies c=d$ for all cardinals $c$ and $d$ imply GCH?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Suppose we add the statement "$2^c=2^d \implies c=d$, for all cardinals $c$ and $d$" to the ZFC axioms. Would we then be able to derive the GCH, the generalized continuum hypothesis?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+2}$ for all $n<\omega$ and GCH holds above $\aleph_\omega$, and you can derive the injectivity of the continuum function from this assumption.
Its consistency follows from [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem), or you may force it directly from the model of $\mathsf{ZFC+GCH}$.

We can have even more from Easton's theorem: we can have $2^{\kappa}=\kappa^{++}$ for all regular cardinals $\kappa$ and $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ for singular cardinals. You can also see that we have injectivity of the continuum function from this situation.

You may ask your assumption proves $\mathsf{GCH}$ at least for *singular* cardinals, and the answer is still negative if you assume large cardinal axioms. It is a result of Woodin that $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$ is consistent for all *cardinals* $\kappa$ if we have a supercompact cardinal (see page 2 of [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2944324) paper).

Comment: The last result you mentioned is due to Hugh rather than Hugh and James. This is mentioned in the paper by Hugh and Matt Foreman. (Better bounds are now known.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thank you for the comment. I did not know that this is solely due to Woodin. (I cited this theorem from Jech.)